# Error al pasar bytes a un archivo

Tags: java

Estoy convirtiendo un archivo el cual estoy pasando a `bytes`, después dejo los `bytes` en un archivo de texto y ese mismo archivo de texto lo vuelvo a leer para convertirlo nuevamente al mismo archivo.

El problema es que cuando creo el archivo, lo crea mal. Esta es la función:

```
public void BytesToFile(String  file, byte [] bytes ) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file+"salida.pdf");
        //escribir contenido archivo
        for (int i = 0; i <= bytes.length-1;i++ ){
            fos.write(bytes[i]);  
        }
        fos.close();
    } catch(FileNotFoundException ex)   {
        System.out.println("FileNotFoundException : " + ex);
    } catch(IOException ioe)  {
        System.out.println("IOException : " + ioe);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. ¿Qué significa exactamente "el archivo lo crea mal"? ¿Y por qué lo llamas "archivo de texto" si le pones una extensión "pdf"? Puedes usar el botón de "editar" para añadir la información a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que tienes un concepto erróneo sobre lo que es un archivo de texto. Si lo que quieres es escribir una cadena de carácteres (`String`) - es decir, texto plano- a un archivo, lo ideal es que tenga el formato `.txt`, para que pueda ser abierto por un lector/editor de texto plano, como lo es Notepad. No obstante, un archivo de formato `.pdf` no está diseñado para contener solo texto plano, sino también texto con formato, mapas de bits e imágenes vectoriales.

Si el archivo tiene formato `.pdf`, va a ser abierto por un lector pdf, que va a interpretar su contenido como contenido específico de pdf, no contenido de texto plano. Por lo tanto, si creas un archivo `.pdf` de esa manera, con solo texto plano, el lector de pdf te va a decir que el archivo está dañado o que no lo ha podido leer.

En resumen, tu método solo puede guardar archivos con contenido de texto plano. Lo que deberías hacer es poner como ruta del archivo algo como: " "C:\Users\pepitoperez\Documents\miTexto.txt", para que de esta manera sea leído por un Editor de texto plano.

En tal caso, si lo que quieres pasar texto a un archivo, debes convertir el `String` a un arreglo de bytes (`byte[]`) y luego a un archivo (`File`), así que tu método necesita varios ajustes.

- No hay que escribir (write) byte por byte. `FileOutputStream` ya tiene un método para escribir todo un arreglo de bytes: `fos.write(arregloDeBytes)`.
- No hay necesidad de lanzar las excepciones `FileNotFoundException, IOException` fuera del método si ya las manejas dentro de él con la declaración try-catch.

### Convertir bytes a un archivo

```
public static File convetirBytesAFile(String textoAGuardar, String rutaArchivo) {
    bytes[] arregloDebytes = textoAGuardar.getBytes();
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(rutaArchivo)) {
        fos.write(arregloDeBytes);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException nfe) {//manejo de la excepción archivo no encontrado
        System.err.println("Archivo No encontrado.");
    } catch (IOException oe) {//manejo de la excepción IO
        System.err.println("Excepción de Escritura.");
    }
    return new File(rutaArchivo);
}
```

El código usa la declaración try-with-resources, que cierra automáticamente (`fos.close()`) el stream cuando termina el try-catch.

Ahora, si lo que quieres es guardar texto en un archivo PDF puedes usar la librería de [Apache PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/). Es fácil de usar:

```
public void textoAPDF(String texto) throws IOException{
    PDDocument documentoPDF = new PDDocument();
    PDPage pagina = new PDPage();
    documentoPDF.addPage(pagina);

    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(documentoPDF, pagina);

    contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.COURIER, 12);
    contentStream.beginText();
    contentStream.showText("Hola Mundo");
    contentStream.endText();
    contentStream.close();

    documentoPDF.save("pdfBoxHolaMundo.pdf");
    documentoPDF.close();
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias, me sirvio

Comment: Si consideras que respondí tu pregunta, puedes marcarla como respuesta aceptada.